# How to solve "AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'" fastapi/python

Tags: python, dependency-injection, crud, fastapi

Whenever I send a post request like `curl -X POST localhost:8000/api/search/86e0220a-e5ae-434c-aad1-c037a58885a9` to my backend I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'query'`

my fastapi_backend.py code:

```
# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        return db
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ' + str(type(e)))
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/api/search/{uuid}", response_model=schemas.ToClient)
def search(uuid:UUID, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks , db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print("/api/search")
    userRequest = crud.get_userRequest_by_uuid(db=db, uuid=uuid)
    background_tasks.add_task(search, userRequest)
    return schemas.ToClient(title="search started",text="let's go!")
```

my crud.py:

```
def get_userRequest_by_uuid(db: Session, uuid:UUID):
       return db.query(models.UserRequest).filter(models.UserRequest.uuid == uuid).first()
```

Does anybody know what my mistake is? I guess it is someting with the db variable, but I am stuck in finding a solution

Comment: I believe it should say `yield db` rather than `return db`.

Comment: Thanks! That made the difference!

Comment: ily @JasonRebeloNeves

Answer (score 0):

Also for me i had like

```
def upload(db=Depends(...))

@app.post("/process")
def process(db=Depends(...))
```

then in my test did

```
app.depovveride....

client.post("/process)
```

And what i didn't realise is the error was coming from the upload function, i had read that dep injection wouldn't work with your own functions but, i thought this just meant testing not like when called from within a route